# How to create different image format using active storage variant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Active storage variant can convert images.For example model.image.variant(resize: '100x100').
My question is that Can i convert images to different image format using variant as active storage is using image processing gem.

Answer (score 2):

To set the format to jpg:

```
model.image.variant(resize: '100x100', format: :jpg)
```

The url on the page won't change, but if you do a save as you can see that it's actually formatting it.

Answer (score 0):

The gem minimagick has this option as well as several other ways you can manipulate images
https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick

I haven't used it for converting file types but there is docs on doing it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had done some research and found out that variant is only used to transform images although minimagick can convert image format.
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32063